# Permission denied: when I try to run a perl cgi program. Apache Server

Tags: apache, perl, ubuntu, cgi, permission-denied

It's wired, but I can't figure out what the problem is. I think it was on apache2 server configuration.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 server, and it worked well when I tried the test perl script.
Such as:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "Hello World\n";
    exit;
```

However, When I tried to run a perl script by using CGI module:

```
    #!/usr/lib/perl 
    use CGI;
    $cgi = new CGI;
    print $cgi->header,
    $cgi->start_html(-title=>'My Page Title'),
    $cgi->h1('My page Header'),
    $cgi->end_html;
    exit;
```

it cannot work. The log file is:

```
   (13)Permission denied: exec of '/ftphome/uploads/cgi-bin/36_CGI_GenerateHTML.cgi' failed
   Premature end of script headers: 36_CGI_GenerateHTML.cgi
```

and Here is my apache2 configure file:

```
    DocumentRoot /ftphome/uploads/public_html/
    <Directory /ftphome/uploads/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /ftphome/uploads/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/ftphome/uploads/cgi-bin/">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem? and how to fix it? Thanks!
ps: All files has been changed permission to 755. In addition, I also change the permission to 775, 777, 555, but no one works.

---

---

Answer:
Thanks for the advice from @Miller and @Borodin. Finally I found it's my fault.
The first line of code should be `#!/usr/bin/perl`, but I wrote to `#!/usr/lib/perl`. Not sure why it will alert for permission denied.

Comment: I don't know if this is the case in Apache2.  However in Apache1, the permissions of each directory in a tree were sometimes relevant.  So, maybe check to see if `cgi-bin` is `a+x` as well?  Don't know if it will help, but all I can think of right now.

Comment: Remove lines one by one from your CGI program until the error goes away. Find the change between the first program and the second that causes the problem

Comment: @Miller I have already set cgi-bin to 775. It must have 'x' permission, since another in the same folder can be run.

Comment: @TerrificJ Yes, that makes sense, and I could've deduced that from the info you already provided.  Then the only solution that I can think of is the same thing that Borodin already suggested, except maybe in reverse.  Start with the script that already works and slowly add lines until it breaks.  Start with `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and then try `use CGI;`, and build from there.  Eventually things will stop working and you'll have more, or you will recreate your 2nd script and a miracle will happen.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for your advice. I return the point from Apache to my code itself. Finally found it was my fault on code. The first line should be `#!/usr/bin/perl`, and I made a mistake to `#!/usr/lib/perl`. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Miller Body, I made a terrible mistake. Just the first line, I wrote `#!/usr/lib/perl` instead of `#!/usr/bin/perl`. It must be the most stupid mistake I have ever made. Thanks for you advice.

Comment: The `Permission denied: exec` message makes more sense now, although it sure would be nice if it said `Permission denied: /usr/lib/perl doesn't exist`.  It's nice that all the information was in your post for someone with eagle eyes to spot.  Kudos to you for not only showing your work to solve your problem, but also doing it.